# Filter Object of Array (having key 'id') that matches element with another array

Tags: javascript

I've object of array, each object has a key 'id', and there is another array whoes elements are actually id of first array, so i want to filter out the objects from 1st array whoes ids are matched from 2nd array

```
const categories = [ 
  { id: 1,
    name: 'Permaculture',
    active: false,
    createdAt: '2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z',
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 2,
    name: 'Food Forest',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Community Supported Farming (CSA)',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 4,
    name: 'Urban Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 5,
    name: 'Roof Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 6,
    name: 'Roof Gardening',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 7,
    name: 'Gardening',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 8,
    name: 'Indoor Plantation',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 9,
    name: 'Soil Culture',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 10,
    name: 'Tropical Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 11,
    name: 'Greenhouse',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 12,
    name: 'Hobby Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 13,
    name: 'WWOOF',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z" },
  { id: 14,
    name: 'Organic Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z" } 
];

const ids = [1, 4, 2];

const expected_res =    [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Permaculture" 
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Urban Farming"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Food Forest"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will filter as per your condition but doesn't keep the ordering of the id though.

```js
const categories = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Permaculture',
    active: false,
    createdAt: '2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z',
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Food Forest',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Community Supported Farming (CSA)',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Urban Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Roof Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Roof Gardening',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Gardening',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Indoor Plantation',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Soil Culture',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Tropical Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: 'Greenhouse',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Hobby Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: 'WWOOF',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: 'Organic Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z"
  }
];

const ids = [1, 4, 2];

console.log(categories.filter(x => ids.includes(x.id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` to achieve this as you want only the `id` and `name` in your result. If the current object's `id` is in the array of `ids`, then you can add it to the `acc` (accumulator)

```js
const categories = [{id:1,name:"Permaculture",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:2,name:"Food Forest",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:3,name:"Community Supported Farming (CSA)",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:4,name:"Urban Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:5,name:"Roof Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:6,name:"Roof Gardening",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:7,name:"Gardening",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:8,name:"Indoor Plantation",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:9,name:"Soil Culture",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:10,name:"Tropical Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:11,name:"Greenhouse",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:12,name:"Hobby Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:13,name:"WWOOF",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z"},{id:14,name:"Organic Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z"}],
ids = [1, 4, 2],

res = categories.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => ids.includes(id) ? [...acc, {id, name}] : acc, []);
console.log(res);
```

However, if you care about the order in which your objects appear, you can use `.map` on the above output to map the number to it's a corresponding object where the number equals the `id` of the object (using `.find()`)

```js
const categories = [{id:1,name:"Permaculture",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:2,name:"Food Forest",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:3,name:"Community Supported Farming (CSA)",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:4,name:"Urban Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:5,name:"Roof Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:6,name:"Roof Gardening",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:7,name:"Gardening",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:8,name:"Indoor Plantation",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:9,name:"Soil Culture",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:10,name:"Tropical Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:11,name:"Greenhouse",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:12,name:"Hobby Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z"},{id:13,name:"WWOOF",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z"},{id:14,name:"Organic Farming",active:!1,createdAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",updatedAt:"2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z"}],
ids = [1, 4, 2],

res = ids.map(num => categories.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => ids.includes(id) ? [...acc, {id, name}] : acc, []).find(({id}) => num === id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.filter` Filter will check if the objects id is inside the id array or not. If it is present it will insert it into the array. After iterating over all the elements it will return the array.

```js
const categories = [ 
  { id: 1,
    name: 'Permaculture',
    active: false,
    createdAt: '2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z',
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 2,
    name: 'Food Forest',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Community Supported Farming (CSA)',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 4,
    name: 'Urban Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 5,
    name: 'Roof Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 6,
    name: 'Roof Gardening',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 7,
    name: 'Gardening',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 8,
    name: 'Indoor Plantation',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 9,
    name: 'Soil Culture',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 10,
    name: 'Tropical Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 11,
    name: 'Greenhouse',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 12,
    name: 'Hobby Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:38:41.000Z" },
  { id: 13,
    name: 'WWOOF',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z" },
  { id: 14,
    name: 'Organic Farming',
    active: false,
    createdAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z",
    updatedAt: "2018-06-18T11:44:56.000Z" } 
];
const ids = [1, 4, 2];
console.log(categories.filter((e)=>ids.indexOf(e.id)!=-1?e:false))
```